# Database Relationship Schema

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am a beginner with database designs. I have two tables `shops and products` with a many to many relation with a pivot table `product_shop`.

In the shop table, this how the structure looks like

**shops table**

id

name

user_id

**products table**

id

name

**product_shop**

product_id

shop_id

**location**

id

name

shop_id

Now  my question is, i want to get all products belonging to a particular user or  location, can i modify the products table to add (user_id & location_id) so as not to write complex queries.

Does it also foul the rules of database design?

Comment: You can but you shouldn’t. It will be much worse and the queries aren’t that complex now. A product is a product, it doesn’t change based on location so that information doesn’t belong there. And if you have 20 users and 20 locations you’ll end up with 400 duplicates in the worst case already.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen  But then how can i retrieve products belonging to a particular user now? Because the `user_id` is in `shop table`

Comment: You join the tables and query based on the user_id, as you would for any other product query, for example what products a shop has.

Comment: About the duplicates you talked about, please look at my update, the location table, every shop enters its location and there are instances where shops could have same location. Meaning location would have two or more places called `virginia` but with different id's.  Does it break the rules?